# linq average of last N

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, lambda, vb.net-2010

Stumped with what looks like simple problem. I have

```
var SummaryCollection = (from n in ...long criteria with group by clause) 
into g select new 
{     MonthYear = g.Key, 
      Amount = g.Sum(p=>p.Amount)}).OrderBy(p=>p.MonthYear);
}
```

I now get data that looks like this

```
Jan2009 $100
Feb2009 $134
... and so on
```

Finally I have

```
  decimal avgAmount = (from x in SummaryCollection select x.Amount).Average();
```

I now need to get the average of last N months where N is input in a textbox by the user.
Please advise how to get avg of last N from an ordered collection using Linq. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the number of items in the collection (or use `Count()`) you can just skip over the first `Count - N` items:

```
 decimal avgAmount = SummaryCollection.Skip(SummaryCollection.Count() - N)
                                      .Select(x => x.Amount)
                                      .Average();
```

Comment: +1. Note that if you can't re-iterate on collection than Count() may not be very performant choice... Not sure how one would be able to do it with single iteration so.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov:  It is possible using a queue, as I've shown in my solution.

Answer (score 3):

I created an extension method that uses a `Queue<T>` that doesn't require calling `.Count` on the sequence, or iterating more than once.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> TakeLast<T>(this IEnumerable<T> @this, int n) {
    var queue = new Queue<T>(n + 1);

    foreach (var element in @this) {
        queue.Enqueue(element);

        if(queue.Count > n) queue.Dequeue();
    }

    return queue;
}
```

To use it, if your list is called `sequence`, just call `sequence.TakeLast(n)` to get the last `n` records.

Comment: Like your solution and plan to use for other situations. For now @BrokenGlass's solution is simpler. +1 thx